# I want to get color X. I have a set of colors Y. Is there some code/formula to find how much of the colors I need to get color X from set Y?

Tags: colors

I'd like to preface this by saying I have not tried anything; as I don't even know where to start.

This also feels like a "color stack exchange" question, but that doesn't exist.

Now, let me elaborate more on my question.

Let's say I have a set of colors (FF0000, 00FF00, 0000FF, FFFFFF, 000000)
and I want to create the color 41AC6A. How do I know how much of each color in the set (by part) to create this color? I have found an example of this at https://trycolors.com/remixer/, yet I do not know how it works. I am not expecting this to be a vending machine, just a sort of conversation-type thing.

Comment: Colour mixing is a complex topic. Which kind of colour mixing do you want? Additive (so like in screens), subtractive (like mixing dyes), or average mixing (like colour dots on newspapers)? All of them have different methods. But for the first "FF0000" is not a well defined colour. And also but the first: it requires a lot of colour theory. But for the first: what parameter do you allow? E.g. do you allow 10% red, or just with no or full 100% red? I think you should tell us what you are doing

Comment: First; subtractive color mixing, Second, I don't really understand
If you are asking for what I am expecting, I am expecting to be able to figure out for example lime, and I know that I have let's just say for convenience purposes cyan and yellow. I want to be able to figure out (programatically) how much of each color I need. Say for lime, I'd need 1 cyan and 1 yelllow. And I'm not really doing anything for any reason, just doing this for fun

Comment: So, you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model#Conversion (which tell you there is no simple formula). You can calculate the result of mixing quantity1 of colour1 with quantity2 of colour2. I think manufacturer do so, and build a "LUT"  or "LUT3D" table and than they interpolate. But in reality things are non-linear ( e.g. cyan is blue on high density) (and yellow is special), so a lot of fine-tuning. But I'm surprised there is not simple (and very approximate formulas). It should not be so complex (but maybe too bad). I'll put in my TODO list.

Comment: Sure, thanks for responding. Didn't really expect anyone to respond, so this is a pleasant surprise. So, thanks for responding. I'll be monitoring this just in case someone has an answer. But thank you for responding nonetheless.